# Navigating word document with vbscript

Tags: ms-word, vbscript

I want to open a word document and jumpt to page 5 with a vbscript. In vba the following works:

```
Set word_app = CreateObject("Word.Application")
set word_doc = word_app.documents.open(doc_path)
word_app.displayalerts = false
word_app.visible = true
word_doc.activate
word_doc.select
word_app.activewindow.selection.Goto wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, 5
```

but in the vbscript i just jump to page 7 (last page of doc) instead.

Comment: Try to use _1_ instead of _wdGoToPage_ and _1_ instead _wdGoToAbsolute_

Comment: that works! but why?

Comment: vbscript does not know the enums so you can use the number values instead (see e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdgotoitem)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using the GoToItem and GoToDirection constants names, just use their number values: [learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdgotoitem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdgotoitem)

Comment: No don't do that, instead include the constants by defining in your code `Const wdGoToPage = 1`.